# Optimize code: pyinstaller keep memory of previous run

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Suppose I have the following Python code:

```
from functions import *
main()
```

If I run it the first time I spend 8 seconds because the first row of importing requires 4 seconds.
If I run it a second time it requires just 4 seconds because it has already located the memory.

When I generate an exe with PyInstaller, is there a way to save time the second and the following times I run the exe as it happens in Python?